# Guarda "dibujo" de canvas en base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Yo tengo un código, para poder dibujar polígonos, utilizando canvas.

Quiero saber como puedo guardar "ese dibujo" para q al cargar la página, se carguen los dibujos hechos(estos dibujos van a estar relacionados a un "item" de una base de datos)

Acá es donde dibuja el pilígono final. Basándose en los "perimetros" marcados con el mouse.

```
if (end) {
    ctx.lineTo(perimeter[0]['x'], perimeter[0]['y']);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    complete = true;
}

ctx.stroke();
```

acá, carga la imagen en el canvas, sobre cual hago el dibujo

```
    function start(with_draw) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.getAttribute('data-imgsrc');

     img.onload = function() {
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            //img.useMap = "#mapa";
            if (with_draw == true) {
                draw(false);
            }
        }
   }
```

Desde ya, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Se me ocurre tener una tabla de imágenes con los metadatos de ésta y una *foreign key* a otra tabla con los puntos (x, y), junto con el orden de cada punto y la referencia a la primera tabla.

Comment: Quieres guardar la imagen o el orden de los puntos??

Comment: Hola. Quería guardar el orden de los puntos. Lo logré. Muchas gracias por su ayuda!